# Como realizar consulta excluyendo una columna en sqlite3

Tags: select, sqlite3, consultar

quisiera saber si me pueden dar una mano con lo siguiente:

Select * from tabla_x;

Al hacer esta consulta obtengo todos los valores, incluido el id, quisiera excluir de esta consulta esta columna(id) para no ver este valor en el resultado final...
Como debería hacerla.... ya se que que podría ponerlo de la siguiente manera:

Select col_1, col_2, col_n from tabla;

sin colocar la col id, pero la idea es no estar colocando en la consulta el nombre de todas las columnas menos la que quiero excluir... saben algún modo de hacer esto?... gracias, saludos.

Comment: si... de esa forma que dijiste.. o todos o elegis los que queres, o mejor.. lo sacas de la vista en el lugar donde los vas a mostrar.. no hay magia en sql ;)